# Diferencias $_SERVER

Tags: php, laragon

Estoy aprendiendo MVC y me ha costado bastante con respecto a las rutas por no saber configurar el servidor.

El problema que tengo es que en el curso que estoy tomando de Udemy de PHP nos piden usar $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], pero este arreglo no lo lee Laragon si entro desde el host virtual que este crea en la carpeta WWW, me toca entrar por el localhost:3000 ejecutando  php -S localhost:3000 desde la terminal de Laragon, pero esto me obliga a entrar por localhost y no por nombreDelProyecto.test.

Ahora, si quiero entrar por nombreDelProyecto.test debo usar:

```
$urlActual = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] ?? '/';
```

si entro por localhost me toca usar

```
$urlActual = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';
```

Quisiera saber cuales son las diferencias y cual es mejor aplicar.

Comment: habría que ver un ejemplo práctico, pero si querés detectar cuando el script es llamado con el servidor de prueba ( `php -s localhost:lalala` ) hay [un ejemplo en el manual de php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.webserver.php#example-467)